# PySpark Kafka - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/JaasContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am encountering problem with printing the data to console from kafka topic. The error message I get is shown in below image.

```
22/09/06 10:14:02 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = ba6cb0ca-a3b1-41be-9551-7956650fbdab, runId = 7dfb967a-8bc2-4c73-91ae-5356cfb21ea4] terminated with error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/JaasContext
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaTokenUtil$.isGlobalJaasConfigurationProvided(KafkaTokenUtil.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(KafkaConfigUpdater.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(KafkaConfigUpdater.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded$(ConsumerStrategy.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.consumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$2(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:578)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThreadRunner.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThreadRunner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.partitionsAssignedToConsumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.fetchLatestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:150)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.initialOffset(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$5(MicroBatchExecution.scala:392)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:385)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:382)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:211)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 50 more
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = ba6cb0ca-a3b1-41be-9551-7956650fbdab, runId = 7dfb967a-8bc2-4c73-91ae-5356cfb21ea4]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/JaasContext
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaTokenUtil$.isGlobalJaasConfigurationProvided(KafkaTokenUtil.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(KafkaConfigUpdater.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(KafkaConfigUpdater.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded$(ConsumerStrategy.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.setAuthenticationConfigIfNeeded(ConsumerStrategy.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.consumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$2(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:578)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThreadRunner.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThreadRunner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.partitionsAssignedToConsumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.fetchLatestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:150)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.initialOffset(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$5(MicroBatchExecution.scala:392)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:385)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:382)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:211)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 50 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ULRICH TEDONGMO\Downloads\test Spark Stream\test 3\pyspark_structured_streaming-main\part4.1\kafka_streaming_json\kafka_streaming_json_demo.py", line 79, in <module>
    orders_agg_write_stream.awaitTermination()
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 101, in awaitTermination
    return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: org/apache/kafka/common/security/JaasContext
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = ba6cb0ca-a3b1-41be-9551-7956650fbdab, runId = 7dfb967a-8bc2-4c73-91ae-5356cfb21ea4]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=false]
+- Project [order_country_name#32, order_city_name#33, sum(order_amount)#53 AS total_order_amount#58]
   +- Aggregate [order_country_name#32, order_city_name#33], [order_country_name#32, order_city_name#33, sum(cast(order_amount#30 as double)) AS sum(order_amount)#53]
      +- Project [orders#24.order_id AS order_id#27, orders#24.order_product_name AS order_product_name#28, orders#24.order_card_type AS order_card_type#29, orders#24.order_amount AS order_amount#30, orders#24.order_datetime AS order_datetime#31, orders#24.order_country_name AS order_country_name#32, orders#24.order_city_name AS order_city_name#33, orders#24.order_ecommerce_website_name AS order_ecommerce_website_name#34, timestamp#12]
         +- Project [from_json(StructField(order_id,StringType,true), StructField(order_product_name,StringType,true), StructField(order_card_type,StringType,true), StructField(order_amount,StringType,true), StructField(order_datetime,StringType,true), StructField(order_country_name,StringType,true), StructField(order_city_name,StringType,true), StructField(order_ecommerce_website_name,StringType,true), value#21, Some(Africa/Luanda)) AS orders#24, timestamp#12]
            +- Project [cast(value#8 as string) AS value#21, timestamp#12]
               +- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@623489c6, KafkaV2[Subscribe[test-topic]]
```

All this are snapshots of the error messages.
I don't understand the root cause of the errors occurring. Please help me.

Following are kafka and spark version:

```
spark version: spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7
kafka version: kafka_2.13-3.2.1
```

Here is my code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import findspark
import time
import os

findspark.init()

kafka_topic_name = "test-topic"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages ' \
                                        'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.3,' \
                                        'org.apache.spark:spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.3 ' \
                                        'pyspark-shell '

    print("Stream Data Processing Application Started ...")
    print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka and Message Format as JSON") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    # Construct a streaming DataFrame that reads from test-topic
    orders_df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()

    print("Printing Schema of orders_df: ")
    orders_df.printSchema()

    orders_df1 = orders_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")

    orders_schema = StructType() \
        .add("order_id", StringType()) \
        .add("order_product_name", StringType()) \
        .add("order_card_type", StringType()) \
        .add("order_amount", StringType()) \
        .add("order_datetime", StringType()) \
        .add("order_country_name", StringType()) \
        .add("order_city_name", StringType()) \
        .add("order_ecommerce_website_name", StringType())

    orders_df2 = orders_df1 \
        .select(from_json(col("value"), orders_schema) \
                .alias("orders"), "timestamp")

    orders_df3 = orders_df2.select("orders.*", "timestamp")
    orders_df3.printSchema()

    # Simple aggregate - find total_order_amount by grouping country, city
    orders_df4 = orders_df3.groupBy("order_country_name", "order_city_name")\
        .agg({'order_amount': 'sum'})\
        .select("order_country_name", "order_city_name", col("sum(order_amount)")
                .alias("total_order_amount"))

    print("Printing Schema of orders_df4: ")
    orders_df4.printSchema()

    # Write final result into console for debugging purpose
    orders_agg_write_stream = orders_df4\
        .writeStream.trigger(processingTime='5 seconds')\
        .outputMode("update")\
        .option("truncate", "false")\
        .format("console")\
        .start()

    orders_agg_write_stream.awaitTermination()

    print("Stream Data Processing Application Completed.")
```

How i solve this error.
Please

Comment: ok @toyotaSupra

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your dependencies including the versions? This usually happens when there are mismatching versions. I had this same error when I was using kafka-clients-0.10.2.2.jar. I resolved it by using kafka-clients-3.3.0.jar instead.

For reference, here are the dependency versions I used successfully:

```
kafka-clients-3.3.0.jar
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.0.jar
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.0.jar
spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.0.jar
```

Comment: this combo works great! Thanks